# Eclipse shortcut key to launch/debug app engine web application

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there anyway to setup a shortcut key (similar to **Alt+Shift+x**) to run/debug the App Engine web application?

Using the mouse every time to navigate to "Run / Web application" is killing the productivity few seconds at a time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+F11 will run the last launched application.  In general, there is a way to bind to "Run As XXXX", but it looks like the Google Plugin for Eclipse doesn't do the necessary magic to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

"`Alt + Shift + d`" pops up a menu to debug then selecting "`J` for java application"(for instance) or whichever applicable to your application should help.